# Older Proliant System Management Driver

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers, hp-proliant, hp

I'm trying to update my server, a DL380 G2, from Server 2003 to Server 2008 (R1 not R2).  Even though it is  an older server, I've been able to get everything working except the Advanced System Management Controller Driver (older version of the iLO driver). The driver for the G2 doesn't work, OS not supported, and any drivers newer (G3-G6) say the firmware is different. This wouldn't be a problem, but this driver controls the fan speed of the server, without it they go at 100% full-time...not cool.

Has anyone gotten a driver to work, or is there a program out there that can fill in the gap and at least control the fan speed? Or am I going to have to get ear plugs or go back to 2003?

Thanks

Comment: This is an in-place upgrade, not a new install?

Comment: No it's a new install. I upgraded the hdd's and decided to see if I couldn't get 2008 on so I could use IIS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System Management Controller driver for one generation of controller is not compatible with other generations (the hardware changes quite a bit every generation).  You will need a G2 driver, and unfortunately there's not one available that supports server 2k8.  You can always try calling HP support and asking nicely, there may be a download available in a non-obvious place (works for me sometimes).

Comment: Noticed the hardware different, and so that's what I figured. Always hopeful though...I'll just live w/ loud fans then.